# Display image when mouse over image

Tags: javascript, css

I have a small icon set as

```
<a class="snapchat" style="margin: 5px 5px 0 -2px;" 
 target="_blank" href="#"><img src="theimage" />
 </a>
```

I need to display a div below with an image when user mouse over the icon.
I tried by adding a hover class to the icon:

```
a.snapchat:hover {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-image: url("hover-image");
    position:relative;
    top:60px;
}
```

but it does not work as expected. Is there a solution to get this?

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/tkux5uav/

Comment: can you please create fiddle?

Comment: This is the effect I want to use: https://www.selenagomez.com/ (snapchat located on top left) when mouse over appears a box with another image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by setting `opacity: 0` and a negative `top` property on the `img`. When you then hover you change these properties to `opacity: 1` and a positive `top` property. This along with the `transition` will make the changes appear as animations.

To do this, you also have to "abstract" the `img` from the `a` so that it can move and hide independently and without affecting it's parent. Do this by setting the parent anchor to `position: absolute` and then the child image to `position: relative`.

There might be better ways you can accomplish this, but I only edited the css. I left your markup untouched.

#### *Modifications after comment:*

[**Example Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cpk52fds/35/)

```css
a.snapchat {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgrey;
}

a.snapchat img {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: -20px;
  transition: opacity .5s, top .5s;
}

a.snapchat:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="snapchat" style="margin: 5px 5px 0 -2px;" target="_blank" href="#">Hover for effect<img src="http://i.utdstc.com/icons/256/snapchat-android.png" /></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris, This is the effect I want to use: selenagomez.com (snapchat icon located on top left) when mouse over appears a box with another image.

Comment: @Yoligrana try the new example. Is that more like what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Chris! I think it will do the trick, how could I change it to be applied to an image instead of "Hover for effect" text?

Comment: Try giving a `background-image` to your `a.snapchat`. You'd probably have to set `width` and so on to it to make it appear well. -- If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as the accepted one.

Comment: you have `position: absolute` and 6 lines later you are overiding it with `position: relative` which one did you want?

Comment: @RabbiShukiGur the relative is for `a.snapchat` and the absolute is for the image. The properties are not for the same element.

Comment: but they are on the same element. I am talking about: `a.snapchat img`

Comment: @RabbiShukiGur Gosh, I must be blind. I must have missed removing it from when I was writing the code. Thanks for spotting this. I have updated the answer and fiddle...

Comment: ;) also, now you can remove `!important` and the note at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If you give an id to the div with the image (for example `id="imageDiv"`), you can manipulate it with CSS like this:

```
#imageDiv {display: none;}
a.snapchat:hover #imageDiv {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
<img id="Image"/>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Image").mouseover(function(){
                $("#Image").show();
            });
            $("#Image").mouseout(function(){
                $("#Image").hide();
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your approach, the easiest implementation would be to have no *img src* but two background images in css, one for each state (hover or not).

Html

```
<div class="snapchat"><a style="margin: 5px 5px 0 -2px;" target="_blank" href="#">  </a></div>
```

Css

```
.snapchat{width:300px;height:300px;display:block;background-image: url("image1")}
    
    .snapchat:hover{width:100%;height:100%;background-image: url("image2");
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;}
```